# How come my web site that does not have Google Maps in it is coming up with this message

Tags: google-maps

Message from webpage

> This web site needs a different Google Maps API key. A new key can be
>   generated at
>   http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/introduction.html#Obtaining_Key.

This web site in on a Intranet of a very large company and this pop-up comes up when it is lunched. This site is write in JSF 2.0 and has no google maps on it. Why am I seeing this message?

Comment: you don't need a map, you will get this message when you load the javascript-file with an invalid key, so take a look if it's loaded somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere on that page you are including the Google Maps API v2 something like this:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=API_KEY&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Remove that line (or those lines) including the `<script>` tags).

Comment: piggy backing on this answer, it could also be loaded asynchronously from any of the js files on your site. so if you can't find it included via a `<script>` tag, make sure your other js files aren't loading it neither